# Malicious Corda Oracle

Tags: corda

I have recently started to get to know the Corda platform from an interoperability standpoint.

I understand that Corda uses Oracles to get external information. But how can we rely on this information being correct?

Example:
Party A has asset X on Corda
Party B has 100 XRP
Party A and B agree to exchange asset X for 100XRP

We set this up on Corda, using the Oracle to tell us when the XRP exchange has taken place, only after this will asset X be assigned to Party B on Corda.

So if the Oracle and B form a malicious coalition, the Oracle can tell Party A the XRP trade has occurred (even though it has not), and party B can end up with asset X and the 100 XRP.

Is there any flaws in my logic? What possible solutions are there? I am currently considering decentralised Oracles. For now, if the oracle owner is the same as the notary, then at least the trust model is the same, but this may not always be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Oracles by definition are trusted third parties, so there is an assumption that it will not team up with any party (can be enforced legally)

To add more trust, you can ofcourse at more oracle as you mention.
This arcticle references various techniques to do so: https://medium.com/fabric-ventures/decentralised-oracles-a-comprehensive-overview-d3168b9a8841